# EBNF Syntax for imaginary language

Tags: ebnf

In school we have been studying metalanguages, in particular, railroad diagrams and EBNF. I received a question where an imaginary programming language (winston) was described in EBNF. Here it is:

```
Digit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
LCase = a | b | c | d
UCase = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J
Operator = + | - | * | /
Logical = < | > | <= | >= | <>
Constant = [-] <Digit>{<Digit>}
Identifier = <UCase>{<LCase> | <Digit>}
Assignment = Set <Identifier> to <Constant> | <Identifier
                    {<Operator>(<Constant> | <Identifier>)}
Condition = <Identifier> <Logical> (<Identifier> | <Constant>)
                    {(and | or) <Identifier> <Logical> (<Identifier> | <Constant>)}
When = (<Assignment> |  <Condition> {<Assignment> | <Condition>})
Statement = <Input> | <Output> | <Assignment> | <Condition> | <When> | <Pretest> | <Posttest>
Program = Start <Statement> {! <Statement>} Stop
```

***The program written below was made with winston but doesn't execute properly. Use the EBNF descriptions to identify the error.***

```
Start
Input J1
Input J2
When (J1 = J2, Set A3 to 0), (J1 < J2, Set A3 to -1), Set A3 to 1
Output A3
Stop
```

My working so far: To me, this program seems legitimate. It is a program so if must start with "start" and end with "stop", which it does. The statements in the middle seemingly are allowed to be in there. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Also, can someone tell me what it means in the EBNF description of a program what this means:`<statement>`

I think it means statements like when and if but Im not too sure. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`When` is comma-separated and the grammar doesn't specify commas at all.

`J1 = J2` -- there is no `=` comparison op in the grammar (see `Logical`), so `J1 = J2` is neither `Assignment`, nor `Condition` and is thus invalid.

`<statement>` -- the grammar wraps symbols in angle brackets on the right-hand side, e.g. `Identifier` on the left-hand and, later, `<Identifier>` in `Assignment` rule -- that doesn't look like a valid [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

Comment: thanks, and could u tell me what is meant by `! <statement>` in the EBNF  description (look in `program`)

Comment: `!` in `<Statement> {! <Statement>}` looks like a statement separator.